# Difference between Time series clustering and Time series Segmentation

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis, data-mining, segment

In the context of time series data mining,  I have read about time series segmentation and time series clustering, but I couldn't differentiate between both. In case they are different, how these methods are correlated with each other?

Well from my understanding  (please correct me if I am wrong), the segmentation is considered as a preprocessing step for the clustering phase. I mean that the segmentation step is used mainly to partition your time series data into segments, let's say into states. After that, a conventional clustering algorithm can be applied to group these segments into clusters (similar segments belong to the same cluster).

As an example, let's say that the segmentation process represents a given time series into the following segments: (S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6). Then after applying the segmentation process, a conventional clustering method is applied to cluster the extracted segments. So we might end up with something like this: 
If k = 3: then K1 {S1, S5}, K2 {S3, S6}, K3 {S2, S4}

Please correct me if I am mistaken, and provide links for more clarification if you have any. 
Thank you

Comment: This question is interesting, but may be considered as "off topic for stackoverflow", because it is not about programming itself. It would be **far** better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ . I could hardly provide a *profound* answer, but regarding the topic in general, be careful to not compute something that is [meaningless](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/meaningless.pdf) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segmentation takes *one* time series, and *splits* it into segments.

Clustering takes many time series, and *aggregates* them into clusters.